# Ag-Grid header groups do not wrap

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am using `25.0.0` for `AgGridReact` and am attempting to style the header group so that the headerName wraps around rather than just overflowing. However as neither `autoHeight` nor `wrapText` works for group headers how do I resolve this issue?

As suggested please find an example of what I am attempting to do here. It is based off the [example provided by Ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-groups/).

```js
<AgGridReact
  defaultColDef={{
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filter: true,
  }}
  debug={true}
  rowData={rowData}
  onGridReady={onGridReady}
>
  <AgGridColumn
    headerName="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
    wrapText={true}
    autoHeader={true}
  >
    <AgGridColumn
      headerName="Athlete"
      field="athlete"
      width={180}
      filter="agTextColumnFilter"
    />
    <AgGridColumn
      headerName="Age"
      field="age"
      width={90}
      filter="agNumberColumnFilter"
    />
    <AgGridColumn headerName="Country" field="country" width={140} />
  </AgGridColumn>
  <AgGridColumn headerName="Sports Results">
    <AgGridColumn headerName="Sport" field="sport" width={140} />
    <AgGridColumn
      headerName="Total"
      columnGroupShow="closed"
      field="total"
      width={100}
      filter="agNumberColumnFilter"
    />
    <AgGridColumn
      headerName="Gold"
      columnGroupShow="open"
      field="gold"
      width={100}
      filter="agNumberColumnFilter"
    />
    <AgGridColumn
      headerName="Silver"
      columnGroupShow="open"
      field="silver"
      width={100}
      filter="agNumberColumnFilter"
    />
    <AgGridColumn
      headerName="Bronze"
      columnGroupShow="open"
      field="bronze"
      width={100}
      filter="agNumberColumnFilter"
    />
  </AgGridColumn>
</AgGridReact>
```

Comment: Put the code inside would help a lot for others to catch up with your issue

Comment: @keikai I didn't have much a of a code but have adapted the ag-grid example code to show my issue, thanks for the suggestion.